# ScrollView on this layout is not working as i want it

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

i have a layout that contain several layouts and outside each layout there is an imageview so i wraped all the layouts under one called container and i want the container to be scrolled i tried several ways but its not what i want as a result.
A little bit of help would be appreciated thank you.

Here is my xml code:

```
enter code here


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/inner_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dip"
    android:background="@drawable/header"
    android:paddingLeft="2dip"
    android:paddingRight="2dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sample_button"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Small"
        android:layout_width="35dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/burger" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actNAME"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Tickets"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
</RelativeLayout>
 ///i want here the scrollview over the container layout
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="390dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:background="#8DAE79" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Ticket 1"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageTicketTwo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageTicketTwo"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Ticket 3"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageTicketThree"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ticket_three" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageTicketThree"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageTicketThree"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Ticket 4"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageTicketFour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ticket_four" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageTicketOne"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageTicketOne"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Ticket 2"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageTicketTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ticket_two" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageTicketOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ticket_one" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where is ScrollView ?? Are making it a parent layout ??

Comment: i did not mention it here cause i looks terrible when i put it.no its not a parent layout i just need to know how to set it above my container layout in a way it wont affect my whole layout.

Comment: ScrollView should be parent layout and Relative will be child. Because ScrollView has restriction that It can have only one direct child. So make sure you take care of it

Comment: Your saying i should declare that layout in beginning as scrollview but this will make my whole layout to scroll i only need the container layout to be scrollable

Comment: Then what exactly you want. can you please elaborate more ??

Comment: i my code i mentioned a line thats says here where i want the scrollview to be take a look at it i need a perfect way to set this scrollview without changing my layout shape cause whenever i declare a scrollview the layout changes!Thank you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32032/discussion-between-brijesh-thakur-and-mostafa-addam)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it b wrapping the container layout with a scrollView just by right click on the container select wrap container and choose Scrollview it will automatically wrap it with its specific attributes.